# How to Downcast the hashtable into an abstract class object

Tags: java, inheritance, hashtable, abstract-class

I'm developing a Feed RSS parser and I'm stuck on what I should get back from it.
I give as input the feed's URL and the elements to read (example: title, description...), and I used to get an arraylist of hashtable, where each key is an element:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>
```

But I'd like to do things better. Since there are classes in my application which manage the news retrieved from different URLs (classes News1, News2, News3) I'd like to return an ArrayList where each element has an abstract method (its implementation will change depending on News1, 2 or 3) to convert the hashtable into the object's attributes.
My problem is that I don't know how to cast every dictionary into an object derived from an astract class...I even tried to create something like this:

```
public abstract class GenericNews extends Hashtable<String, String> {
    public abstract News getObject();
}
```

but I can't downcast it. How could I do it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you show the code which does not work? But, in general you can't take an object of type ArrayList<K,V> and down cast them to a new sub type. You have to create an object of that new sub type in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to cast it.  You will need to create a new instance of your GenericNews object which wraps the HashTable, and return that.

Also, I'm not sure it's wise to actually extend Hashtable in Generic news - why not make your ArrayList an `ArrayList<GenericNews>` and have methods on GenericNews to access items within it, such as `getNewsItem(String keyword)`.

Comment: Do you mean I shouldn't make the GenericNews class abstract?

Comment: No, I mean that extending HashTable is disingenious.  Your Generic News object USES a Hashtable to maintain its internal news items, that doesn't mean it IS a Hashtable.

Comment: ok, so I will have something like this:

'public class GenericNews extends Hashtable<String, String> {
    private Hashtable dictionary;
    public String getItem(String item){ ...}
}'